# When do spells unlock?

Tags: magicka-2

I know that I need to play, but when do they exactly unlock? Is there a list? I have finished first level and unlocked 3, and I wonder when the rest will unlock.

This is how it looks at the moment:
(didn't even unlock all the types, btw I'm asking the spells, not the spell types)
[image: spells view]

This loading screen image shows all the spells in first slot (for example):
[image: all spells in first slot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that (at least for the first spells) they unlock while progressing the world.

It might be possible that you have to find some book or go on higher difficulties to unlock more powerful spells.

Also, the trial mode seems to unlock spell.